# I'm trying to make the pictures only go 10 Rows down, the Loop Back up to the next row. Can anyone help me?

Tags: excel, vba

This is what I have so far, I just can't figure out how to loop the pictures back after 10 rows.

```
Sub InsertPictures()
    Dim PicList() As Variant
    Dim PicFormat As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sShape As Shape
    Dim MaxWidth#
    On Error Resume Next
    PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
    xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
    If IsArray(PicList) Then
        xRowIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Row
        For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
            Set Rng = Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, -1, -1)
                .LockAspectRatio = True
                .Height = 100 * 3 / 4
                Rng.RowHeight = .Height
                If MaxWidth < .Width Then
                    MaxWidth = .Width
                End If
            End With
            xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 1
        Next
        Rng.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
        Rng.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
        Rng.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
        For Each sShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            sShape.Left = MaxWidth / 2 - sShape.Width / 2
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Chris!! I figured that out after I posted.  First time user, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Simply track `xRowIndex` change compared to original row.  When it's > 10 different update row and column

Refactored (with a few other improvements)

```
Sub InsertPictures()
    Dim PicList() As Variant
    Dim PicFormat As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim sShape As Shape
    Dim MaxWidth#
    Dim xColIndex As Long, xRowIndex As Long, lLoop As Long
    Dim xColIncrement As Long, xRowInit As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' <-- better to be explicit rather than rely on implicit ActiveSheet reference
    'On Error Resume Next <-- dont just ignore all errors
    PicList = Application.GetOpenFilename(PicFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
    xColIncrement = 1 ' <-- adjust to how many columns to increment by
    xColIndex = Application.ActiveCell.Column
    xRowInit = Application.ActiveCell.Row
    xRowIndex = xRowInit
    With ws
        If IsArray(PicList) Then
            For lLoop = LBound(PicList) To UBound(PicList)
                Set Rng = .Cells(xRowIndex, xColIndex)
                With .Shapes.AddPicture(PicList(lLoop), msoFalse, msoCTrue, Rng.Left, Rng.Top, -1, -1)
                    .LockAspectRatio = True
                    .Height = 100 * 3 / 4
                    Rng.RowHeight = .Height
                    If MaxWidth < .Width Then
                        MaxWidth = .Width
                    End If
                End With
                xRowIndex = xRowIndex + 1
                ' Check if rows is > 10 different to initial row
                If xRowIndex >= xRowInit + 10 Then
                    Rng.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
                    MaxWidth = 0
                    xColIndex = xColIndex + xColIncrement
                    xRowIndex = xRowInit
                End If
            Next
            Rng.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth / Rng.Width * Rng.ColumnWidth
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When watching it run, it stacks the pictures correctly, but before it is finished it has the pictures stack on top of each other in Column A.  Maybe i'm trying to make it to difficult.  Ultimate goal, Import all pictures from a folder that allows them all to be viewed easily in one worksheet.

Comment: @JamesPrescottBerry ok, that's new info, I had assumed the only issue you had was wrapping the row as described in your OP.  The code places the images in the cells I think as you want, but then moves them with the code `For Each sShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes                 sShape.Left = MaxWidth / 2 - sShape.Width / 2 Next`.. You may want to adjust column width and reset `Maxwidth` each time row is reset

Comment: @JamesPrescottBerry Update code to reflect these suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit simplified version:

```
Sub InsertPictures() ': DrawingObjects.Delete: Cells.Delete  ' used for testing
    Dim picList, pic, picFormat As String
    Dim rng As Range, sShape As Shape, MaxWidth As Double

    picList = Application.GetOpenFilename(picFormat, MultiSelect:=True)
    If Not IsArray(picList) Then Exit Sub  ' picList = False if no files selected

    Set rng = ActiveCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False   ' optional to make it faster

    For Each pic In picList
        With Shapes.AddPicture(pic, 0, 1, rng.Left, rng.Top, -1, -1)
            .LockAspectRatio = True
            rng.RowHeight = rng.RowHeight * 10
            .Height = rng.Height
            If MaxWidth < .Width Then MaxWidth = .Width
        End With

        Set rng = rng(2) ' move to the cell below
    Next

    rng.ColumnWidth = MaxWidth * 255 / 1342.5

    For Each sShape In Shapes
        sShape.Left = rng.Left + (rng.Width - sShape.Width) / 2
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's question _I'm trying to make the pictures only go 10 Rows down, the Loop Back up to the next row_

Comment: @chrisneilsen I still have no idea what that means (I am surprised that you understand it), so I tried to think of something based on the original code and the comment in your answer